# Can getting rear ended crack your engine mount?

Tags: engine, honda, accord

I was sitting at a dead stop at a traffic light when a pickup truck rear-ended me. I drive a Honda Accord and the bumper withstood the impact pretty well but still needs to be replaced. Immediately after the incident I heard rattling from my engine and it's a cracked engine mount. I just had the engine mount fixed a year ago so my question is whether it's typical for them to only last a year and whether an impact like that could have cracked it?

Comment: Sounds like the hit wasnt that bad if only the bumper needs to be replaced. Something like that normally should not crack your motor mounts in my opinion. You dont even have any drivetrain components in the back.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same engine mount which you had replaced a year ago? There is usually more than one engine mount.

Comment: Agreed with Zaid, 4 mounts is common. And when one of them goes, the rest tend to wear out quicker.

Answer (score 3):

If your engine/motor mount was degraded at the time of impact it could have broken.  By degraded I mean, if it was seriously rusted or on it's way to failure.

A healthy motor mount should take a serious amount of force to break.

A photograph of the point of failure would help to identify if it was on it's way to failure or not.  As well, the failure could have been on the frame, the bolt or the engine.  Determining exactly where the failure occurred should give you the breadcrumbs to truly answer your question.